# What is generating errors?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0;
        String[] name = new String[i];
        int[] roll = new int[i];
        float[] total = new float[i];
        float[] per = new float[i];
        System.out.println("Enter the no of student/s \n");
        int no=sc.nextInt();
        for(i=1;i<=no;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Name of Student.");
            name[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the RollNo of Student.");
            roll[i]=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the Subject marks");
            int[] marks = new int[5];
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                marks[i]=sc.nextInt();
                total[i]+=marks[i];
            }
            per[i]=(total[i]/500)*100;
        }
        System.out.println("To get details press Y to cancel press N.");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = reader.next().trim().charAt(0);

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 'Y':
            for(i=0;i<=no;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Name: "+name[i]);
                System.out.println("Rollno: "+roll[i]);
                System.out.println("Total marks: "+total[i]);
                System.out.println("Percentage: "+per[i]);
                if(per[i]>=80)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Distinction!!!");
                }
                else if(per[i]>=60&&per[i]<=80)
                {
                    System.out.println("First Division");

                }
                else if(per[i]>=40&&per[i]<=60)
                {
                    System.out.println("Second Division");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Fail");
                }
            }
        case 'N':
            System.out.println("Exit");

        }

    }
}
```

When Scan line for student name comes program terminates. Please, what can be the reason to generate errors. I am new to Java.

Comment: Because the size of the name array isnt enough.

Comment: Does the program terminate normally or do you get an error? If the latter is true and it is an `Exception`, could you please provide the stack-trace?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the array sizes after you know the number of students. Your are creating an array of size 0 here:

```
int i=0;
String[] name = new String[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is AraryIndexOutOfBound,you have not assigned the string array .
Your code should be some thing like this,rework it thoroughly,lot of bugs are there

```
  int no=sc.nextInt();
        String[] name = new String[no];
        for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Name of Student.");
            name[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the RollNo of Student.");
            roll[i]=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Enter the Subject marks");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change a size of an array once it is created!

as suggested by @inwi above

**be careful you are creating array with size zero here!**

```
int i = 0;
String[] name = new String[i];
int[] roll = new int[i];
float[] total = new float[i];
float[] per = new float[i];
```

This is the problem in your code. create the arrays after accepting a number of students as input

```
// ....
System.out.println("Enter the no of student/s \n");
int no=sc.nextInt();
String[] name = new String[no];
int[] roll = new int[no];
float[] total = new float[no];
float[] per = new float[no];
```

**also be careful the way you access array elements, arrays are 0 based in Java
so start your iteration from i = 0; check this in all your code**

```
for(i=1;i<=no;i++) {
```

happy coding!!
good luck

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `roll` and `name` array is initialised of size 0 from the below lines of code and you are trying to access their element at index 1 in for loop and so you must be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception

```
int i=0;
        String[] name = new String[i];
        int[] roll = new int[i];
```

And then you are accessing it the below code starting from index 1

```
System.out.println("Enter the RollNo of Student.");
            roll[i]=sc.nextInt();
```

You need to re initialise your roll array based on number of student as below

```
roll = new int[no];
name = new String[no];
```

As you are working with array you need to change your for loop as below

```
for(i=0;i<no;i++)
```